# How to use translator for JSON response in Symfony2?

Tags: json, symfony, internationalization, translation

I implemented translations in my Symfony2 webapp. Now I created a controller action, where I don't return a regular `Response` which passes arguments to a twig file where I can handle translations, but I want to return data as a `JsonResponse`.

```
public function myAction() {
    $json_data = array(
        'status' => 'success',
        'message' => $this->get('translator')->trans('change_password.flash.success')                   
    );
    return new JsonResponse($json_data);
}
```

Now in a twig file I could define the default translation domain like this:

```
{% trans_default_domain 'MyBundle' %}
```

But where can I define the default translation domain? Remember that I bypass a twig file when I return as `JsonResponse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this
    ->get('translator')
    ->trans(
         'change_password.flash.success', 
          array(), 
         'message_domain'
    )
```

Have a look at the [API doc](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Translation/Translator.html) for the Translator:

```
trans(string $id, array $parameters = array(), string $domain = null, string $locale = null)
```

Comment: You were some microseconds faster, I was just about to post the answer which I found. Exactly the same :-)

Answer (score 0):

The default message domain can be set like this:

```
$defaultDomain = 'mydomain';
$this->get('translator')->trans('Symfony2 is great', array(), $defaultDomain);
```

[Found here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#using-message-domains).